# What if AMP page content will not be updated for a long time?

Tags: seo, google-search, amp

I'm new to this Google's Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP). I've to develop various AMP pages. I have a query regarding the SEO for that.

What if my page does not update from a long time, will it be still visible in the search results?

Because my AMP pages will be static. For example. I have a salon, in which I'll be providing 5 services. These services will have a price (which is not likely to vary) and duration of the service. So, the content of my page will stay static and fixed to the long period of time. Will it affect the Google search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's does not affect(Both for AMP or non-AMP pages). Google does not de-index any page that does not update for a long time (even I see some sacred-texts.com pages which is not updated from 10 years).

The Page will de-index only, if it return 4xx or 5xx status(error) for a long time, for example hosting is expire or domain does not resolve it or page is deleted/hacked, then Google will de-index it, but if your page is simply accisible for 20 years, then Google will still index your page for 20 years, it does not look for wether page is updated or not.

So the page updation does not affect anything for indexing purpose but it **slightly** affect in ranking score, because Google like fresh content which is updated and accurate with time.

Answer (score 2):

AMP HTML itself is not a ranking factor. But speed is in some %. There are some results where AMP pages gain some privileges like for example news carousel.
Your page is not a tipical news page so you have to consider it as a normal page from a SEO point of view, but faster and mobile friendly. So it will not affect Google search result as long as no other pages fast like your one will be created in the same field more rich in content. You just don't have to let look your page like obsolete. For example, as you said all services will have a price, just add something like "year 2017 prices", and remember to update your page with "year 2018 prices" next year. So it will be perceived as an up to date informative page (that it is in real) and will not drop even if not update for many months.